# Maven Tags For Quartz 1.8?

Tags: maven, quartz-scheduler

I inherited a legacy Java Servlet webapp I am slowly rewriting into something a bit more modern.

The webapp runs a nightly scheduled task thanks to Quartz and depends on these library files:

- quartz-1.8.0.jar
- quartz-all-1.8.0.jar

I don't know Quartz, but I learned JUST enough to fix a harmless exception it was throwing when I took over the webapp. From that experience I learned that there have been significant API changes since version 1.8. 0. Someday when I finish rebuilding more vital parts of the webapp I want to take the time to learn quartz and fully update the libraries.

For now I would be happy to learn what Maven tags I would add to my pom.xml to get both of those jars.

When I boot up WebLogic 11g I get a message telling me that there is a Quartz 1.8.5. Is 1.8.5 fully compatible with version 1.8.0 ?

If so what would be the Maven tags I would need to upgrade to that?

Thanks much in advance for any information.

Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven Tag for Quartz,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Yes, 1.8.5 is fully compatible with version 1.8.0.

Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

First i would search in Maven central for those artifacts like this:

http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.quartz-scheduler%22%20AND%20a%3A%22quartz%22

For quartz-all seemed to be not existing in the given version.

http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|quartz-all

I would assume that you only need the quartz artifact and not quartz-all.